# Change text in separate text document with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, txt

I want to change the text in a text file called data.txt but I don't know how to change it with script. This is my code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#btn").click(function(){
            $("#txt").load("data.txt");
            
        });
    });
</script
```

I've got it to work so that the text, that I've written in the document from the begging, pops up on the screen, but I don't know how to access it and change it with the script. Is there some command like this:

```
$change("#data.txt").text = "HelloWorld";
```

that can be used to change it or are you forced to use some other program for it to work?

Thanks

Comment: You need to pass the edited text to your server, then the server can save the file.

Comment: And how am I supposed to do that exactly? @Teemu

Comment: Client-side code can't do this.  It has no knowledge of or access to the server's file system.  (It doesn't even know that the data is persisted on a file system, it could just as easily exist in a database or anywhere else.)  The data is persisted server-side and only *returned* to the client upon request.  The client would need to send updated data to the server and then server-side code/functionality would overwrite the persisted data.

Comment: I've no idea, because you haven't given any information about your server architecture.